# Are there any differences in R if I use a "pnorm" or create a distribution with rnorm for Kolmogorov-Smirnov?

Tags: r, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

For testing distributions existing in base R, say normal or beta distributions, is there any difference if I use a one-sampled or two-sampled Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with same parameters?

For example:

ks.test(x, "pbeta", shape1, shape2)

Or

ks.test(x, rbeta(n, shape1, shape2)

Of course, with n being big enough, and in my case study x having 100 continuous values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Power is the issue; you're introducing (completely unnecessarily) additional random variation into the problem, making the estimate of the effect noisier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option will depend on the specific data set you generate, so it will be affected by random variation. Chances are that this will imply that the second test has worse statistical properties (power in particular). You could in principle find out about this simulating many data sets and estimating power and type I error probability, but I'm not sure whether that's worthwhile because intuitively it's rather obvious that you sacrifice precision using the second approach.

Chances are also you are right believing that with sample size of the generated random data set n going to infinity you may ultimately get something equivalent, but of course large n means also more computational effort. So whereas this is a fun idea, I have a subjective probability north of of 99% that version 1 will be superior (I don't give it 100% as I can't prove it, at least not in reasonably short time, but...), as version 2 basically does the same thing but with random noise introduced, which won't help matters.

I add that there is another issue with version 2, which is that the rbeta command uses a pseudo random number generator that in fact isn't truly random Beta. Chances are this won't make much of a difference though unless n is extremely large.

PS: whuber in the comments writes: "Imagine, for instance, a proposal in a textbook Binomial(n,p) situation to test the hypothesis p=1/2 by generating a second Binomial(n,1/2) sample and conducting a two-sample t-test, rather than applying the usual one-sample t-test. That should help make the issues more apparent."

Comment: Perhaps by "sacrifice precision" you meant "sacrifice *power*"?

Comment: @whuber In principle I could also imagine that the finite sample type I error probability is affected (the test is asymptotic with probably better approximation for version 1). If this comes out too large, power may not necessarily suffer, so I meant "precision" in a "at least one of the two error probabilities, maybe both" way.

Comment: Hmmm... Isn't the fundamental problem that the two procedures are implementing different tests altogether?  What is the implicit null hypothesis in each case?

Comment: @whuber: That's the fun bit... the null hypothesis is the same;  it's the specified distribution in version 1, and distribution of x equal to the known distribution that generated the second data set (which is the same as tested in version 1) in version 2.

Comment: IMHO the null is completely different in the two cases.  In the first case the null is that the data originate from a specified Beta distribution.  In the second case the null is that the *two* datasets -- the first one along with a synthetic sample -- originate independently from a common distribution.  I have a hard time equating those two nulls, even knowing the synthetic sample does arise from a specific Beta distribution.

Comment: @whuber But then the distribution generating the second data set in version 2 is the same specified Beta distribution, so the only possibility that the two data sets in version 2 come from the same distribution is (...) ;-) I have to admit though that this may be somewhat compromised by the fact that the random number generator isn't perfect.

Comment: "Somewhat compromised" in the sense of not achieving the nominal test size, among other things, as well as creating a *randomized procedure,* which probably was not intended.  Imagine, for instance, a proposal in a textbook Binomial$(n,p)$ situation to test the hypothesis $p=1/2$ by generating a second Binomial$(n,1/2)$ sample and conducting a two-sample t-test, rather than applying the usual one-sample t-test.  That should help make the issues more apparent.

Comment: @whuber This is in line with my answer, and a nice idea, so I added it.